# Class can't read its attribute

Tags: python, pytorch

I following [this pytorch tutorial](https://github.com/python-engineer/pytorchTutorial/blob/master/09_dataloader.py)

On the basis of this link I wrote the following code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import Dataset,DataLoader
import numpy as np
import math
class WineDataset(Dataset):
    def __int__(self):
        xy =np.loadtxt("wine.csv",delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32,skiprows=1)
        self.n_samples =xy.shape[0]
        self.x_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 1:])
        self.y_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [0]])
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index],self.y_data[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples
# create dataset
dataset = WineDataset()
# get first sample and unpack
first_data = dataset[0]
features, labels = first_data
print(features, labels)
```

But when I run the code, it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\Dataset_DataLoader.py", line 19, in <module>
    first_data = dataset.__getitem__(0)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\Dataset_DataLoader.py", line 13, in __getitem__
    return self.x_data[index],self.y_data[index]
AttributeError: 'WineDataset' object has no attribute 'x_data'
```

This line is also  written on GitHub:

```
# create dataset
dataset = WineDataset()

# get first sample and unpack
first_data = dataset[0]
features, labels = first_data
print(features, labels)
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: is it `__init__` or `def __int__(self):` ? it should be `__init__`

Comment: def __init__self()

Comment: it should be `def __init__(self)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `def __int__(self)` to `def __init__(self)`. Right now you have no constructor.

Comment: ouuu i look  now, i have written int sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You should change `def __int__(self)` to `def __init__(self)`, otherwise the constructor is not created ! so you should pay attention to the syntax.

take a look to [the Python documentation here !](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__)